# JavaScript filter instead map

Tags: javascript

I have this code:

```
const uniform = {
  zone: 'BOTTOM'
}

const sizes = [

  {
    _id: 'sizeId2',
    zones: ['BOTTOM'],
    value: '48'
  },
  {
    _id: 'sizeId3',
    zones: ['BOTTOM'],
    value: '42'
  },
]
sizes.map((size) => (size.zones.includes(uniform.zone) ? {
  _id: size._id,
  value: size.value,
} : null))
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pmiranda/945fsdw7/5/

```
// here I'm trying another way than map and the ternary
console.log(sizes.filter((size) => (size.zones.includes(uniform.zone) && {
  _id: size._id,
  value: size.value,
})))
```

I wonder, how could I replace that `map` with a `filter`? Because I think that mapping with a ternary with null could be done in a better way, plus, in the `map` way I'm getting that `null` in the end, I want to not add it to the array

Comment: There's no method in js to manipulate collections, like selecting specific properties (like `.select()`). All you can do is  `filter`, then iterate. Or just chain `filter`.`map`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you'd filter then map:

```
sizes.filter(size => size.zones.includes(uniform.zone)).map(size => ({
  _id: size._id,
  value: size.value,
}));
```

You probably need to return the result, or assign it to a variable.

Comment: yes, this is fine, thanks. I was thinking on a map inside a filter, I was trying to return the needed values without map, but I can't see how.

Comment: I'm pretty uesd to LINQ in C# - In C# it's pretty clear that you filter with Where, before you project the structure you want with Select. I therefore always use filter first in javascript, and then consider map to be the projection stage - thinking about the pipeline like that always works.  It's good practice to know what data structure you have at each point in the pipeline, such clarity allows you to reliably use reduce in javascript, which is very powerful for all kinds of aggregation.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const uniform = { zone: 'BOTTOM' }

const sizes = [

  {
    _id: 'sizeId2',
    zones: ['BOTTOM'],
    value: '48'
  },
  {
    _id: 'sizeId3',
    zones: ['BOTTOM'],
    value: '42'
  },
]

// reduce

const newSizes = sizes.reduce((acc, size) =>

{
  if(size.zones.includes(uniform.zone)) {
    acc.push(
    {
    _id: size._id,
    value: size.value
    })
  }
  
  return acc;
 }, []
 )
 
 console.log(newSizes);
```

Using either `map` or `filter` does not make sense in the cuurent usecase as you are not utilizing the return value.

If you need to just loop over the array and create new entries (containing or nnot containing null) you can use `forEach` or `reduce`.

From the "comments", `reduce` is more suitable for you.

Comment: In the fiddle I had a console.log with the value of that map, I just put the code portion that I want to tweak. The idea is to have the same array without `zone` key and with the condition of the ternary operator

Answer (score 0):

Without `map` and `filter`, just create new array

```
let newSizes = [];
sizes.forEach(({zones, _id, value}, key) => zones.includes(uniform.zone) && (newSizes[key] = {_id, value}))
```